# Work with HTML.EditorForPassword() in MVC4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I created a "Editlogin.cshtml" page where I can edit all properties of an user. My user has password so when I change a his password then it works okay. However when I do not write any passwors, my page has to write me a password, but sometimes I do want to leave the previous password. I use Entity Framework and I use an attribute for Password property in a model class:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public global::System.String Password
    {
        get { //omitted}
        set { //omitted}
    }
```

It is a double-edged weapon. When I create new user, I must have to write new password. However, if I edit an user, I would like sometimes to leave a previous password.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to opt out the password change from form editing in a separate functionality (change password), password field resetting is good for security purposes.

Comment: It is not possible. I would like to do it in a such way.